# VF Page Error Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number, received Text

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, map, collection

I'm getting below error when I'm trying to pass values from map to pageblocktable in Visualforce page.

> ERROR : Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number,
>   received Text

VF PAGE :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable" title="Invoice line item" value="{!Invoiceitemsmap}" var="inv" >

                        <apex:column headerValue="Nicomatic Part No"><apex:inputtext value="{!Invoiceitemsmap[Inv].Name}" required="true" /></apex:column>  

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

APEX CODE:

```
Public Map<Integer,List<Invoice_line_item__c >> Invoiceitemsmap{get;set;}
            contactList = [Select Name,Client_Part_No__c from Invoice where Id =:"SomeId"];
            totalCount = contactList.size();
            Invoiceitemsmap=new Map<Integer,List<Invoice_line_item__c>>();
            Invoiceitemsmap.put(totalCount,contactList);
            System.debug(Invoiceitemsmap);
```

Comment: `Invoiceitemsmap[Inv]` would give you a `List<Invoice_line_item__c >`, you would have to rewrite your code with use of wrapper classes to make code simpler.

Comment: You mean I need to write wrapper class and pass that wrapper list to there then it will also be the same right it is also a list only

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because, you are trying to use the dot notation on list variable on visualforce page.

As your `Map` structure is `Map<Integer,List<Invoice_line_item__c>>`,you will have to use two `PageBlockTable's` in order to display your `Map` in visualforce page, in first iteration of `PageBlockTable`, it will return you `List<Invoice_line_item__c>` and you cannot access the individual field's value i.e. `Name` from list without using the `index`. So in order to display this `List` again, you will have to use one more `PageBlockTable`.

Your visualforce page should be something like this

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable" title="Invoice line item" value="{!Invoiceitemsmap}" var="inv" >
    <apex:column >
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Invoiceitemsmap[Inv]}" var="inv1">
            <apex:column headerValue="Nicomatic Part No"><apex:inputtext value="{!inv1.Name}" required="true" /></apex:column>
        </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```